# Flutter web, "wild" timers, any way to stop a timer after F5 is pushed?

Tags: flutter, timer

I have a Flutter web application where one widget is showing a text (actually a clock).

The timer is a `Timer.periodic` implementation like this:

```
class WatchText extends StatefulWidget {
  const WatchText({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<WatchText> createState() => _WatchTextState();
}

class _WatchTextState extends State<WatchText> {

  late String _timeString;
  Timer? timer;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    timer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _timeString = DateTime.now().to24HourMinuteSecondString();
    timer?.cancel();
    timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer){

      setState(() {
        _timeString = DateTime.now().to24HourMinuteSecondString();
      });

      print("timer update : $_timeString");

    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(_timeString, style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24,));
  }
}
```

Which triggers like this:

[image: Normal triggering]

But when the user hits the F5 button for refresh, suddenly I have two or more events trigging the timer:
[image: Multiple triggering]

How do I catch (and kill) the "wild" timer-events ?, after/when the user hits F5 (or even Ctrl+F5 (in Chrome))?

Comment: tested `home:WatchText()`, seems working fine for my case. In case you are interested only assign on null case, you can do `timer ??= Timer`, or to check the timer weather timer is ticking `timer?.isActive`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I tested your suggestion in and even testing if it is running and tried to cancel it `if(timer?.isActive==true) timer?.cancel`, but it didn't sort out.

Comment: you can also listen the keyboard, `dispose` method should have work. btw I've failed to reproduce the issue on windows10 chrome

Comment: @YeasinSheikh the "cruel" fact, is that `@override dispose()` isn't called when clicking F5 (or Ctrl+F5), so the timer seems to still be alive in the "context" of the browser window. And when `@override initstate()` is called the `timer` value is null again. 

When navigating out of the Page where this Widget is used, the timer stops, but after hitting F5 when timer is running it still are alive afterwards (doubled up), but when navigating out of the Page, only the first (iligimit) timer seems to be alive...

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I did as you, made a simple example, then it works as expected. But the `@override dispose()` still isn't called, so I am not entirely sure of the timer is properly stopped. By doing the changes mentioned before in the app I am handling, I see that now there isn't more than two events each minute, and they seems even, not arbitrary. And the "wild" one is still triggering if I am navigating to another destination in the app. May be the problem is elsewhere...

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your `initState` by moving `super.initState();` to the top and creating a `bool _isTimerRunning = false` flag to check whether the timer is still running or not might solve your issue.

**initState**

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _timeString = DateTime.now().toIso8601String();
    _startTimer();
  }
```

**_startTimer**

```
  void _startTimer() {
    if (!_isTimerRunning) {
      _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
        setState(() {
          _timeString = DateTime.now().toIso8601String();
        });
        print("timer update: $_timeString");
      });
      _isTimerRunning = true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: By the way, super.initState() is *always* supposed to be first, just as super.dispose() is *always* supposed to be last.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I tried as you suggested, putting super.initState() first, it didn't do any changes, F5 refresh still bring up two or more events every second, but the principle is good.

Comment: I didn't say it would solve it, but it might contribute to it being wrong.  Apparently there's something else that still needs solving.